# How is UnrecognizedSelector even possible in Xcode9/Swift4?

Tags: swift, selector, xcode9

The code completion fills in the name of the method inside the `#selector(` then proceeds to crash at runtime with an error that the selector is unrecognized, (IllegalArgumentException).

What was the point of redoing the selector syntax as no longer just strings??

Here is the creation of the selector:

```
headerAddButton.addTarget(section, action: #selector(addActivityToSpecificDay(sender:)), for: .touchDown)
```

Section (referenced here) is the header section of the tableview (forgot to mention, this code was working before Xcode 9):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
```

Here is the method signature of the handler:

```
@objc func addActivityToSpecificDay (sender :UIButton)
```

In the same source file of course. But read the question: if the code completion can find it how on earth do I get a runtime crash?

Comment: Is your method tagged with `@objc`, overriding a method tagged with `@objc`, or satisfying the requirement of an `@obj` protocol?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Yes it has @objc

Comment: Is the function in the class represented by `section`?

Comment: Is `section` an instance of the class where `addActivityToSpecificDay` is defined?

Comment: @vacawama good call, I updated the question to include the section definition

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You seem to have missed the point of the question both I and @vacawama asked. Your addTarget call is claiming that the class represented by `section` has the function `addActivityToSpecificDay`. But clearly that's not true. That function is in your view controller class, not the view class used for your section header.

Comment: I got that. I did not write this code. I was just asked to look at it when it caused a crash today. How did this code ever work? I looked at blame and it was this way and worked before.

Comment: Silent downvotes. I thought about editing the title of this but I do think it is a valid question: if they went to the trouble to destringify selectors, and add code completion, why does it offer me a syntax that will fail at runtime? Clearly exactly what a helper tool should never do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the target like so:

```
headerAddButton.addTarget(section, action: #selector(addActivityToSpecificDay(sender:)), for: .touchDown)
```

Because your `#selector` doesn't qualify `addActivityToSpecificDay` with a class, it is obviously matching up with some method of that name in the current class, not in whatever class `section` is.

There are two options:

1. Move `addActivityToSpecificDay` into whatever class `section` is (for the purposes of illustration, let's say it was `SectionClass`) and reference that class in your `#selector`:

   ```
   headerAddButton.addTarget(section, action: #selector(SectionClass.addActivityToSpecificDay(sender:)), for: .touchDown)
   ```
2. Or keep `addActivityToSpecificDay` in the current class, but change the target of `addTarget` to `self`:

   ```
   headerAddButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addActivityToSpecificDay(sender:)), for: .touchDown)
   ```

You ask:

> What was the point of redoing the selector syntax as no longer just strings??

It validates that the selector’s function exists and is well formed (which is a very good thing), but it obviously cannot validate that the selector’s class happens to be the same class as some other parameter (the `target` in this example). The compiler can’t reliably know how the `addTarget` method uses the selector nor that there is some special relationship between two parameters. That is left to the developer. The `#selector` syntax helps, but it is not a magic bullet.